# Open Source eMOCHA Alternative

Tags: open-source, mobile, health

eMOCHA was a free open-source application, developed by the Johns Hopkins Center for Clinical Global Health Education. eMOCHA is designed to assist health programs in developing countries improve provider communication and education, as well as patient care, by coordinating wireless devices with local server-based clinical training and patient care support services.

Now this platform is no longer open source, are there any alternatives that come close to achieving the functionality of the eMOCHA platform?

Thanks.